# Entity framework 6 code first one to one instead of one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I got over a project where EF6 code first is used. I have 2 classes where a relationship one to many is set, the same is set in Fluent API.

When I create both parent/child in the same step everything is fine and saved, but when I create the parent first, save it and then I want to add a child I got an exception that states that these two entities are in relationship 1 to 0..1 and it is not saved.

Is there any way to first create only the parent and then add a child to it?

Model classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
                     .HasRequired<Parent>(s => s.Parent)
                     .WithMany(s => s.Children)
                     .HasForeignKey(s => s.ParentId);
```

In database I see the foreign key `ParentId`. Parent can exist without a child if I am right. Everything is saved with `dbContext.SaveChanges()`

Exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Project.dll

Additional information: Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Child_Parent_Target' of the relationship 'Project.DAL.Child_Parent' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
```

Comment: So you want to change the relation from one to many to one to one?

Comment: I thought about it too, but first I would like to know if there is any way how to make it work in current relationship, also I don't have a clue from where is EF taking `1 to 0..1` relationship. I wan to know where this problem comes from so I can have a look at it and see if it can be fixed or change of relationship is needed.

Comment: Please update the question posting the exact exception you are getting

Comment: Thanks, please update the answer showing the code you use to save a child entity

Answer (score 0):

Consider giving your child a ParentId Property

```
public class Child
{
    public int ChildId {get; set;}

    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

If you do this, you follow the **[code-first conventions (click to view)](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx)**. If you follow the conventions Entity Framework understands that Parent - Child is a one-to-many relation: A parent has zero or more childs and a child has exactly one parent.

The nice thing about following the conventions is that you don't need your fluent API statements. Entity Framework knows that the parent is required, that the parent has many children and that the foreign key to the parent is ParentId

Back to your problem. After adding the ParentId to your child, you can add a parent without children and add children later.

After adding ParentId you can add a parent and add children later

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // By convention will become the foreign key to Parent:
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

public void Main()
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
    {
        var addedParent = dbContext.Parents.Add(new Parent()
        {
             Name = "Phil Dunphy",
        }

        // if you do not want to add a child now, you can SaveChanges
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        // now addedParent has a ParentId, you can add a child:
        var addedChild = dbContext.Children.Add(new Child()
        {
            Name = "Luke Dunphy",
            ParentId = addedParent.Id,
        };
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: when I change my model class this way and then try to add children to already existent parent I get exception `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parents_ParentId". The conflict occurred in database "CLDash0001", table "dbo.Parents", column 'ParentId'.`

Comment: Apart from typing errors, the program runs in my solution. Can it be that you have problems because you are doing this in an already existing database and you have changed your database model? Try this code in an empty project with just a Parent / Child / MyDbContext. In the constructor of DbContext pass a name of a not-existing database, so it will be created for you.

Comment: Don't thinks so, I have also model classes with same code as you post so it is not a problem of DB, I think that the problem is somewhere in saving, in code which is responsible for correct adding keys and so on. Code is quite complex and there is no `SaveChanges()` call after adding entries, everything is saved at once, it is a wizard with few steps and `SaveChanges()` is called from parent controller, where are methods which updates values of children because till this moment are all entries keep in `TempData[]`